# setTimeout and location href and event loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I need help in understanding why this code snippet changes the window location to facebook website but not to stackoverflow. Does `location.href` take some time to execute in the browser that the engine executes the next set of statements before changing the location?

```js
function fb(){
    console.log("fb");
    location.href="https://facebook.com";
}
function so(){
    console.log("so");
    location.href="https://stackoverflow.com";
} 
function run(){
    setTimeout(fb);
    so();
} 
run();
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's something unique to location.href where it doesn't block or happen immediately.  You can recreate the same behavior by testing `location.href="https://stackoverflow.com"; location.href="https://facebook.com";`. So setting location.href is probably somewhat of an asyncronous process since it probably calls some native browser (C/C++ ?) code to start the navigation process. The second line of javascript will always run way before the browser gets very far in loading a new page. Just making an educated guess here, though.

Comment: @matmo Makes sense. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: This is related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521172/is-javascript-location-href-call-is-asynchronous

Comment: @callback yes it seems related. This test also appears to show that multiple consecutive `location.href` statements result in the location change that's done by the last statement.