# Javascript Execution Order - When window.location.href happens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom-events

I took a look at this [is-javascript-location-href-call-is-asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521172/is-javascript-location-href-call-is-asynchronous) and this [what the heck is the event loop anyway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&vl=en) but there is no explanation of the defined behavior of `href` of `window.location`:

The following is the script order in source code:

1. DOM elements
2. `<script>` at the bottom having `doc.ready`.
3. Further `<script>` tags.
4. `doc.ready`'s callback goes into the CB queue because all DOM elements are available in step 1 and there are only further script tags ( This callback stays in the queue until all the scripts in step 3 complete its execution and empties the call stack. **Correct?** )
5. `window.location.href=/error` inside the `fail()` of sync AJAX. It does not immediately redirect. So it is async.

`// synchronous wait method ~ >= 0.5sec` inside this `fail()` method just after (for testing) [TAG: 1]

6. call stack becomes empty here as there no more scripts to exec

**Question:** If `href` also acts like Events/XHR/Timeouts, does `href` at `step 5` go into the event queue? If so, exactly **when** ? ( Events, AJAX, setTimeouts have defined behavior of when it gets into the queue but what about `href` redirection? )

**Experiment:** If the synchronous wait is there after `step 5`, then `href` redirection happens **"most"** of the times. But **"sometimes"** `doc.ready`'s callback is also executed.

**Question:** If `href` acts like Event/XHR/Timeouts, then it is always the second in the queue after `doc.ready` and so even with the synchronous wait, it should always execute after `doc.ready`. But it did not based on the above experiment!! So it shows `href` does not involve event queues, right? Then, what is the defined behavior of `href` when other Events/XHR/Timeouts are around and relate to Call Stack or Event/CB Queue ?

Answer (score 0):

Stop. [Research Javascript Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). JS executes code linerly. When an event - asynchronous call generally speaking - is encountered it is pushed to an "event queue" and JS execution keeps going. The event queue is 'first in, first out'. There's no telling what is in the queue at any moment so the execution of any given event - your href - is unpredictable - it is not 'by chance.' If program execution was 'by chance', then computers would not even work.

Comment: I edited the question. Please check. I understand call stack, event loop and callback queue. Saw the JSConf video. `doc.ready` goes into the callback queue when DOM elements are ready. But is there any definite way of knowing when does the `href` event (if at all it is an event) goes into the queue? Even `href` is assumed to make use of event queues, `href` does not conform to the working of the event queue based on the experiment.

Comment: Is my question clear now? Can you please take a look?