# Should setting window.location.href cause the "old" page to stop running JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm seeing unexpected behavior when setting `window.location.href`. My understanding is that the current page will be navigated away from immediately -- effectively ignoring subsequent JavaScript in the containing script. However, this is not what I'm seeing in practice (Firefox, Chrome and mobile Safari). I'm setting `window.location.href` when I encounter an error condition (e.g. missing some data) and yet the script continues to run and spew a bunch of errors because of said error condition. (This also applies to `window.location.assign`.)

Example:

```
function handleError() {
    window.location.href = "https://example.com"
}

function doWork(id) {
    if (!id) {
        handleError();
    }
    var oops = id.split("-");
    // a bunch of errors spill into the console, onerror listeners, etc.
}
```

Comment: Hm, but why set `window.location.href` instead of just `window.location` itself? That said, any page JS keeps running until the current page gets unloaded, which doesn't happen on window.location _assignment_, but after the browser tries to load the URL and has something to swap in (be that a new page, an error page, or whatever else)

Comment: It doesn't, so don't count on it - so adjust your control flow accordingly.

Comment: Are you calling this doWork() function through a submit button?

Comment: Why not document.body.innerHTML = ""; throw new Error(""); and immediate catch prior to handleError? If handleError is on the stack of events, but doesn't terminate propagation, everything will fire anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add a return after the guard clause?

```
function handleError() {
    window.location.href = "https://example.com"
}

function doWork(id) {
    if (!id) {
        handleError();
        return 
    }
    var oops = id.split("-");
    // a bunch of errors spill into the console, onerror listeners, etc.
}
```

Comment: I'm doing more/less that, but I was hoping to find a definitive, documented answer describing how this is expected to work.

Comment: Well you've tested the behaviour, which imo is better than documentation, take a look at this post also.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521172/is-javascript-location-href-call-asynchronous