# Load images after page is done loading?

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to make a website unblocked, but as a prank I replaced all images on the unblocked page with Rick Astley. But, once I activate the js bookmarklet, it replaces the images and THEN redirects the page... take a look at the code below:

```js
  javascript:var ghjetgh=prompt('Enter the url(includng the https://):');
window.location.replace('https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:%27+ghjetgh+%27+&cd=11&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us%27);

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");for(var i=0, l=imgs.length;i<l;i++){imgs[i].src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTeq-t73dty81noWDtxBxHdGUg2gNEyXrL1B1aJTtAkNm7urrdgBYCpsPO-xargqqibLEU:https://i.insider.com/61135525ad63f30019501966%3Fwidth%3D700&usqp=CAU"};
```

For what reason is it not working the way I wanted to, and how could I fix this? I have looked everywhere, and nothing I tried worked.

Comment: 1. It takes time to move away from page. 2. You can't do anything once user exited page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is JavaScript location.href call asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521172/is-javascript-location-href-call-asynchronous)

Comment: it explains why it happened, but not how to fix it... thanks anyway

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.